# QGIS Converting USGS GeoTIFF to Garmin CPE

Tags: qgis, kmz, garmin

I'm totally new to QGIS.  I'm trying to use a USGS GeoTIFF and convert it to a KMZ via the Garmin plugin.  I can load the GeoTIFF as a raster file and view it.  When I run the Garmin plugin I get an error on a line saying it has an "int" data class.  Is there some setting change I need to make in QGIS before using the plugin?

```
2022-07-23T10:52:14     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/tnoll/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\GarminCustomMap\GarminCustomMap.py", line 347, in run
  mapSettings.setFlags(QgsMapSettings.Antialiasing | QgsMapSettings.UseAdvancedEffects | QgsMapSettings.ForceVectorOutput | QgsMapSettings.DrawLabeling)
 TypeError: QgsMapSettings.setFlags(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the *exact* error message.

Comment: Bug: https://github.com/NINAnor/GarminCustomMaps/issues/24 and looks like the plugin hasn't been updated for a couple of years.

Comment: Thanks; too bad.  I can get a lot of the maps I want in KMZ format from the USDS, but some other maps are only available as GeoTIFFs.  I'll work on another path.